# C# problemas em carregar Data Grid usando DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, datagrid

Boa noite. Tenho um `dataGrid` o qual carrego usando *Entity Framework*, porém no `dataGrid` minha data aparece `MM/dd/yyyy`, quero retirar a hora e formatar a data para `dd/mm/yyyy`, e no campo validade quero retirar apenas a hora parte do código que gera o `dataGrid`

**Código**

```
using (ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())
 {
     var lista = ctx.Produtos.ToList();
     return lista;
 }
```

**DataGrid**

[image: Imagem da tela/ grid]

Já tentei modificar o banco porem continuo com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifique a prorpiedade [DefaltCellStyle](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2).[Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=netframework-4.7.2) para a [cadeia personalizada de formatação de tempo e data](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) "dd/MM/yyyy".

**Supondo** que o seu `DataGridView` se chame `dataGrid` e o índice da coluna tempo/data em que queira aplicar a formatação seja `3`, o código seria esse:

```
dataGrid.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

**EDIT:**

Como informado que o objeto é um `DataGrid` e não `DataGridView` então o código é:

```
(dataGrid.Columns[3] as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "0:dd/MM/yyyy";
```

ou então em XAML dentro do atributo 'Binding' da coluna exibindo a data, caso ela esteja presente, adicione `StringFormat='0:dd/MM/yyyy'`.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{StringFormat='0:dd/MM/yyyy'}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Boa tarde eu não consegui aplicar, devo mexer em alguma parte do código alem desta?

`dgProdutos.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"`

está me retornando o erro DataGridColumn náo contem uma definição para "DefaultCellStyle" que aceite o primeiro argumento do tipo "DataGridColumn"

Comment: `dgProdutos` não é um 'DataGridView`? Pergunto porque na pergunta está marcado a tag `DataGridView` e essa resposta só se aplica a `DataGridView`. Se esse é o caso me informe a classe que `dgProdutos` instancia.

Comment: este é o código no xaml 
`<DataGrid x:Name="dgProdutos" Margin="78,172,70,243" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="DgProdutos_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionMode="Single" />`  

Parte do codigo de montagem do dataGrid  
`dgProdutos.ItemsSource = ProdutoViewModel.ExibirProdutos();`  

Restante da chamada  
`using (ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())  
                {  
                    var lista = ctx.Produtos.ToList();  
                    return lista;  
                }`

Comment: Vasques, você estava correto estou trabalhando com dataGrid e não dataGridView, eu não conhecia a diferença entre eles.

Comment: @LucasSantos Fiz a modificação para DataGrid.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado, realmente me ajudo muito